# Executing c# Unit Tests with Jenkins

Tags: c#, unit-testing, powershell, selenium, jenkins

I am running c# Unit Tests through Windows Jenkins and while executing tests console output window shows me same error for all the tests:

> Error Message:
>      Test method Levan_Test threw exception: 
>   System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: Access is denied
>   Stack Trace:
>       at System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendInput(Byte[] oldKeyboardState, Queue previousEvents)
>      at System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.Send(String keys, Control control, Boolean wait)
>      at System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait(String keys)

It looks like there is some problem with permissions or power shell command execution.

code snippet:

```
Thread.Sleep(1000);
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id=\"solutionsDropdown\"]/div/i")).Click();
Thread.Sleep(1000);
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id=\"solutionsDropdown\"]/ul/li[2]/a")).Click();
Thread.Sleep(1000);
SendKeys.SendWait("{Enter}");
```

Comment: Yep, that's sure what it looks like.  Any additional clues, like maybe some code to look at?

Comment: I'm finding plenty of advice about this on Google.  Looks like you're not the only one who has had this problem.  In particular: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42501443/access-denied-error-while-running-powershell-script

Comment: I added the code

Comment: Did you have a look at that other Stack Overflow article?  Your problem is fairly unremarkable; you're using  an account on the target machine that doesn't have the necessary permissions.

Comment: I tried to run Jenkins service as administrator instead of local system but it did not start the service at all.

Comment: _This could be totally off_: By any chance, do you _really_ intend to use Windows Forms? Did you perhaps mean to use [WebElement.sendKeys](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#sendKeys-java.lang.CharSequence...-)? There is a way to [directly send Enter to a WebElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1629053/typing-enter-return-key-in-selenium).

Comment: I can not replicate command:  SendKeys.SendWait("C:\\Users\\Levan Taktakishvili\\Downloads\\Test.docx");

Comment: I posted an answer to my question.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of research I found out that: if you are running Jenkins as a service, it can't do stuff that interacts with the desktop, e.g., Windows forms applications. You would want to have a build agent running on the desktop using JNLP as a normal user that runs these tests.